# How to permanently save data in your program

Tags: python

The question may not be so clear on first glance and i'm sure it exists somewhere but i've searched and didn't find anything

My question is, i have a program in which it saves words that you give it inside a text file and i have this variable called `count` and for each time it saves this variable gets incremented

my problem is here, so whenever i restart the program, the count variable resets to 0

is there a way to solve this?

Comment: save the value of a count in a database or in a text file. the program will fetch count before running further.

Comment: Where and how do you save the variable?

Comment: @vuun0 i've thought about that but i thought there would be a better way, maybe like a module that would make this much easier thanks so much for your contribution, your comment was really helpful!

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev 

If you're asking me, then i have a program to save words and their translation in other language in a text file, i want to keep count of the amount of words i've translated so far,

the variable is saved inside the code and everytime I run the "program.exe" file the  count variable is set back to 0

Comment: @Moaz_pr yes it was question. Why did I ask? Because there are several modes of `open()` function. If you open file in `w` mode - you rewrite file, if you open file in `a` mode  - you add lines to the end of file. It it really hard to understand what you have done wrong without your code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers are made for storing data, so there is plenty of ways. Use a text file, JSON file, database, ...

Simple proof-of-concept solution:

```
# ON program start
try:
    with open("count.txt", "r") as f:
        count = int(f.read())
except OSError: # file not there or unreadable
    count = 0
except (TypeError, ValueError): # file content not an int
    count = 0

#...
# whenever count changes
with open("count.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(count))
```

Storing more complex data. [JSON format](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation) can store numbers, strings, boolean values as well as lists and objects (key-value-pairs).

```
from json import dump, load

def load_data(filename="data.json"):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except ...: # add error-handling here as above

def save_data(data, filename="data.json"):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

# on start
data = load_data()

# on change of data
save_data(data)
```

Comment: I actually thought about this but i thought there was like a better and easier way, but thanks, this was really helpful!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to include an Property file in your project and update that file property file counter value each time your counter increments.